# Execution of prepare statement in one transaction, while another transaction is running in the same database

Tags: sqlite

Imagine a single database file. I open this database file **twice**. In one connection I begin a transaction and I execute various statements. In the other connection (the second), I also begin a transaction and I prepare various statements in this transaction, **without executing the statements**.

Is it possible to do this **without being blocked in the second transaction?**

Sqlite 3, being used in multithreaded mode.